# "das gleiche" oder "dasselbe"

Tags: meaning, difference

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Dasselbe vs. das Gleiche, what's the difference?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/574)*

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *der/die/das gleiche* und *der-/die-/dasselbe*? Ist es richtig zu sagen:

> Wir haben an der selben Universität studiert.
>   Ich habe das gleiche Auto wie du.
>   Sind das dieselben/die gleichen Unterlagen, die Sie mir schon zukommen gelassen haben?

Comment: http://www.selbe-gleiche.de/

Comment: @Iris: Other questions is English however, so no strict duplicate.

Comment: @guidot, das stimmt, allerdings gehe ich davon aus, dass hier alle Englisch können, aber nicht alle Deutsch.

Comment: @Iris: [Relevante Meta-Diskussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/807/2594).

Comment: Zwei Personen können den gleichen Pullover tragen, aber nicht denselben. Eselsbrücke: "den gleichen" sind zwei Wörter, "derselbe" nur ein Wort.

Answer (score 3):

Der Unterschied zwischen "das gleiche" und "dasselbe" bezieht sich strenggenommen auf den Unterschied zwischen Gleichheit und Identität. Eine Tafel Schokolade enthält viele *gleiche* Stücke, *dasselbe* Stück Schokolade kannst Du trotzdem nur einmal essen.

Ein anderes Beispiel: Du nimmst von einem Stapel Papier zwei Blatt und schreibst auf beide denselben Text. Dadurch sind die Blätter *gleich*, aber noch lange nicht *identisch*. Sie sind *das gleiche*, aber nicht *dasselbe*.

In Deinem Beispiel über die Unterlagen kommt es darauf an, ob man zwei Ausdrucke beispielsweise desselben PDF-Dokuments als "dieselben Unterlagen" (weil das gleiche Dokument) oder "die gleichen Unterlagen" (weil zwei physisch getrennte Ausdrucke) betrachtet.

Im Alltag wird diese Unterscheidung aber oft nicht streng eingehalten, ähnlich wie die Unterscheidung zwischen "anscheinend" ("es scheint so und ist auch so") und "scheinbar" ("es scheint so, ist aber tatsächlich anders").

Comment: Korrektur: Du nimmst von einem Stapel Papier zwei Blatt und schreibst auf beide den gleichen Text. :)

Comment: @user24635 Ich glaube schon, dass es denselben Text ist, nicht den gleichen. Der Text ist der Inhalt, nicht die Buchstaben

Comment: @user24635 Das ist ein ähnlicher Fall wie bei dem Beispiel mit den Unterlagen, und geht schon fast ins Philosophische. Wenn man einen Text als eine abstrakte Entität betrachtet, die unabhängig von seiner physischen, niedergeschriebenen Form ist, dann ist es *derselbe* Text, eben zwei mal niedergeschrieben. Wenn man sich konkret auf die physische Tinte auf dem Papier bezieht, dann es ist der *gleiche* Text.

Answer (score 1):

Die beiden Begriffe ordnen sich zu "Gleichheit" (*Equality*) und "Identität" (*Identity*), zwei Begriffe, die auch in der Informatik vorkommen (und in vielen anderen Wissenschaften).

*Gleich* - Wertegleich, gleich aussehend, mit den gleichen Attributen, aber ein "anderes Ding". Beispiel: Zwillinge

*Selb-* - Identisch, nicht nur von seinen Attributen, sondern von seiner Identität, also "beides mal dasselbe Ding". Beispiel: Spiegelbild